# Playonlinux on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: unmet dependency error

Tags: software-installation

Iam not able to install playonlinux on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. following msg is being displayed

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
playonlinux: Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is a virtual package
         Depends: imagemagick but it is a virtual package
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To update the package sources followed by

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

To resolve unmet dependencies.